# Como substituir trecho dinamico {{trecho}} de uma string em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Eu recebo uma *string* que é gerada dinamicamente exemplo: "Texto dinâmico {{parametro1}} , mais um pedaço do texto {{parametro2}}".

Tenho no C# um código parecido com esse: onde o nome é o mesmo que está entre chaves e a propriedade valor é a que precisa ser inserida no lugar.

```
List<Parametro> parametros = new List<Parametro>(){
   
  new Parametro(){
     
     Nome="parametro1",
     Valor="Programando em C#"
  },
new Parametro(){
     
     Nome="parametro2",
     Valor="preciso de ajuda!"
  }
}
```

Como posso substituir cada trecho da *string* que recebo pelo valor de cada parâmetro?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que vc quer e qual é o seu problema. Vc poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: Quero substituir os valores que estão entre chaves pelo valor que está na propriedade valor da classe parâmetro .

Comment: porem não tenho conhecimento de quantas chaves vão estar no texto e nem dos valores que vou precisar substituir. O texto e os valores são dinâmicos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você pode fazer de forma simples basicamente é o uso do método  [`Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) existente no .NET. Se precisar de maior sofisticação, teria que desenvolver um algoritmo próprio.

```
var texto = "Texto dinâmico {{parametro1}} , mais um pedaço do texto {{parametro2}}";
foreach (var item in parametros) {
    texto = texto.Replace("{{" + item.Nome.Trim() + "}}", item.Valor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UuUxYP). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tkUN9V). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ReplacePart.cs). Ali fiz um método de extensão também para usar como um facilitador se isto for usado várias vezes.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, bem simples, tando código na cabeça nem percebi que seria simples. Agradeço.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o Replace do String

Tente:

```
String teste = "Um teste {{parametro1}} outro teste {{parametro2}}";

teste = teste.Replace("{{parametro1}}", "valor1");
teste = teste.Replace("{{parametro2}}", "valor2");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 4):

primeiro passo, transforme a sua lista de parâmetros em um dicionario, depois monte uma expressão regular para encontrar todos os parametros na sua string de entrada, por fim faça a substituição.

```
public static string InterpolarString(string input, Parametro[] parametros)
{
    var dicParams = parametros.ToDictionary(param => param.Nome, param => param.Valor);     
    var regexp = new Regex(@"{{\w+}}");     
    var output = regexp.Replace(input, match => {
        var nome = match.Value.Substring(2, match.Value.Length - 4);
        return dicParams[nome];
    });
    return output;
}
```

Por fim, um exemplo funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EkcCKR)

Comment: Bem completa sua resposta, muito obrigado, gostei muito.